# Enviroment variable doesn't change in CMD and programs

Tags: windows-registry

I changed enviroment variable in Windows (user variable as well as system variable, to eliminate overwriting etc). I did it from "Edit the system enviroment variables" and from Registry editor and the result is the same. Then I ran the CMD, but it didn't see the change. Moreover, when I ran program that uses enviroment variables it didn't see the change too. They show previous value. How is it possible?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski not at all, because Command Prompt or used program was ran only after changing variable value.

Comment: Including this? "This is important because applications launched by another process inherit their environment variables from their parent. As such, if you launch cmd from explorer, you get the variables as explorer sees them."

Comment: A logout or reboot will probably resolve such issues.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, I closed everything, then I ran "Edit the system enviroment variables", changed value, saved change and ran Command Prompt. When I checked value of variable it showed the previous one.

Comment: @harrymc but it should update without reboot

Comment: "Closed everything" including windowless `explorer.exe` that gives you the taskbar and the start menu?

Comment: Okay, very probable that it is due to explorer.exe is running constantly in the background so it didn't reload new value.

Comment: But on the other hand on my second computer explorer.exe is running constantly in the background and there isn't such problem.

Comment: I think, the problem has just been resolved. The cause of the issue was cmd running in the background, not explorer.exe.